# Time format not updating until app is restarted - WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm using `DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()` to get the short time.

If my device is in 24-Hour time format, short time returned will also be in 24-Hour format (which is expected). Now, I launched the app, did FAS and changed time format to 12 Hours. This time when I check for short time, it's returning time in 24-Hour format. :(

Now, after changing time format to 12-Hour and relaunching/restarting the app, I'll get short time in 12-Hour format. Means, the time format has effect only when I restart/relaunch my app. Is this the expected behavior? Can somebody confirm? How can I overcome that?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this really a practical problem? Users won't switch that much.

Comment: That depends on user. My point is, the code is not working as expected and why? That's what I'm searching for.

Comment: It is unclear how you did the test. At least, can you confirm `DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()` get called again after changing time format?

Comment: @har07 - It's straight forward. Add a button that shows 'DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()'. Now, launch the app, tap the button, check the time format. Now, do a FAS, change time format, and check the time format again. It never changes. I think, it's clearly explained in my post.